# Recovering Linux soft raid 5, disk stays as spare

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid5, disaster-recovery

I got disk failure on my Centos Linux soft raid 5 array (mdadm). I replaced one of the disk and started to rebuild the array. Next time I checked the status, the rebuild was failed.

This is the status right now:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : inactive sdc1[3](S) sdd1[2] sdb1[0]
      4883277760 blocks

unused devices: <none>
```

-

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Mon Aug 23 22:37:36 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465135936 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jan  1 23:30:32 2002
          State : active, degraded, Not Started
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : 6af06755:6fc93cba:c083764e:1e719c94
         Events : 0.27470

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       0        0        1      removed
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1

       3       8       33        -      spare   /dev/sdc1
```

/dev/sdc is the brand new drive. If I try to remove it and add again, it still stays in spare. How should I try to start rebuild this?

Comment: Could you try to remove failed/detached devices with 'mdadm /dev/md0 --remove failed' and 'mdadm /dev/md0 --remove detached' and to dump  details again?

Comment: Tried to remove failed and detached disks but no change to md0 details. Btw. im in read only filesystem, this should not affect?

Comment: So the line with "removed" device is still there?

Comment: Yes, no change to mdadm --detail /dev/md0 output.

Answer (score 1):

**How should I try to start rebuild this?**

Depends on if you care about the data.  Assuming you do, there is a [guide over here](http://www.kossboss.com/sparetoactive).
Note that RAID-5 has [some issues](http://www.baarf.com/), which were enough for me to convert most of our environment to RAID-10 or just plain mirrors.

I'm not sure what `/dev/md0` is, but if your root (`/`) filesystem is on there (or any filesystem you're distribution would need, like `/usr` for the utilities), then I would suggest you get a Live-Boot CD for your Linux Distribution and boot-off of that before attempting a repair.

Once you've rebooted off of a Boot-CD, run the following to find your array;

`mdadm --assemble --scan`

From there, you can either follow the guide above in an attempt to *safely* recover the RAID-5 array.
Or you can nuke and rebuild the entire thing.

Note that you might want to consider a more redundant configuration, such as RAID-1 & a spare.
(Unless you can get a 4th drive, then RAID-10)